# Is the norm on $c_{00}$ different from norm on $c_{0}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

In FUNCTIONAL ANALYSIS written by Balmohan V. Limaye page $64$ the definition of $c_{0}$ and $c_{00}$ is as follows
$$c= \{ x \in l^{ \infty}: x(j) \ \  \mbox{converges in K as}\ \  j \to \infty \},$$
$$c_{0}= \{ x \in c: x(j) \to 0  \mbox{ as}\ \  j \to \infty \},$$
$$c_{00}= \{ x \in l^{p}: \mbox{ all but finitely many } x(j) \mbox{'s are equal to 0}\}.$$
$1)$Is the norm on $c_{00}$ different from norm on $c_{0}$?
This question was created in my mind because $c_{0}$ is a subspace of $l^{ \infty}$ and its norm is $\lVert x \rVert_{ \infty}= \sup \big\{ |x(j)| , j=1,2,...\big \}$ ( sup norm) but $c_{00}$ is a subspace of $l^{p}$ and its norm is $\lVert x \rVert_{p}=( |x(1)|^{p}+|x(2)|^{p}+...)^{ \frac{1}{p}}$ . $2)$Is it possible to use $ \lVert \cdot \rVert_{\infty}$ for $c_{00}$?

Attention. $K= \mathbb{R}$ or $ \mathbb{C}$ and $x=(x(1), x(2), ...)$.

Comment: $c_{00}$ is a dense vector subspace of all $\ell^p$s and $c_0$. $c_{00}$ cannot be made complete w.r.t. any norm by the Baire category theorem. Perhaps this is why there is no canonical norm in textbooks for $c_{00}$.

Comment: "dense in $\ell^p$" for $p<\infty.$